# Сравнение информации из текстового файла и из данных оборудования d'link (Python)

Tags: python, telnet

```
for st in clean_data:
    new_mac_table = macTable()
    new_mac_table.vlan = re.findall(r'v\d+',st)
    new_mac_table.mac  = re.findall(r'\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w',st)
    for i in container_white_list:
        if new_mac_table.mac == i.mac:
            continue
        else: container_new_mac_table.append(new_mac_table)
```

В общем смысл такой: я по телнету подключаюсь к оборудованию, тяну таблицу маков, затем тяну из файла маки которые нужно удалить из таблицы. В цикле (`for st in clean_data:`) я перебираю табличку маков полученную с длинка, затем создаю объект типа `macTable()` и инициализирую его поля данными из таблицы по средством регулярных выражений. Затем цикл (`for i in container_white_list:`) в котором я перебираю список мак-адресов т.н белого листа и условие если мак из таблички совпадает с маком из белого листа, то ничего не делать, иначе записать в контейнер объект. Проблема в том что условие почему то не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `if i.mac in new_mac_table.mac:`

Comment: пробовал так делать уже((

Comment: я провел небольшое исследование и выяснил что проблема не в том читаю с файла, а в том что получаю с оборудования

Comment: Врядли вам кто-нибудь сможет помочь не имея примера данных которые вы получаете "с оборудования" и примера данных из файла...

Comment: могу примерно навести, потому что нельзя в инет выкладывать физ.адреса: с оборудования после распарсивания приходит лист в виде: влан         мак-адрес(прим.: v102       00-00-00-00-00-00)  я для отсеивания с помощью регулярок забираю мак, затем в файлике белого листа у меня хранятся несколько маков которые нужно найти в таблице и допустим удалить

Comment: разделите задачу на несколько шагов: 1- сохранить сырые данные с устройства. Проверить, что результат ожидаемый (формат, значения разумные)¶ 2- распознать полученные данные и сохранить в структурированном виде. К примеру в json формате: `[{"vlan": "...", "mac": "..."}, {"vlan": "...", "mac": "..."}]` Проверить, что ожидаемые данные получились. Вместо сохранения на диск, можно просто функцию, возвращающую список словарей/namedtuple, создать¶ 3- Зная, что предыдущие два шага работают корректно. написать цикл с "white list", используя руками созданные данные для тестов.

Comment: все равно что-то не получается... ладно буду еще проводить исследования

Comment: в общем я не знаю как но получилось, хотя не должно было получится. Я поменял методы findall() на search() и добавил еще группировку после поиска (.group())

Comment: забыл добавить что убрал еще 'r' перед паттерном регулярки

Comment: в общем проблема опять возникла когда я перенес и оптимизировал скрипт на freebsd, увы решения пока не знаю